# How to get look ahead for XMLStreamReader?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I can not find any `peek` or `unread` function in the [XMLStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html) documentation. What is the preferred way to get at least one token look ahead in order to parse a list of child elements as in the the HTML list for example?

```
<ul>
  <li>
  <li>
</ul>
```

When I create a recursive decent parser with parse functions for `ul` and `li` the `li` parse function has to terminate when it finds the closing tag of `ul`, but it must not consume it, because the `ul` parse function needs it to succeed.

I am used to solve such problems with `peek` or `unread` but they seem to be missing. What is the preferred Java way to solve this problem?

**Update**: I implemented the parser without look ahead using the XMLStreamReader.

Comment: so is there any specific reason for not using SAx Parser ?

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya: I was told that [StAX](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP2.html) is the most modern and best API for new programs. What would be the benefit of using SAX?

Comment: ok i was just conforming that since this could be handled by SAX. It could be done with SAX as well . Please use the "XMLEventReader" it has a peek method that does return the next event without iterating over it.  A very good tutorial can be found here ,    http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-stax2/index.html

Comment: @SomBhattacharyya I guess you have provided the wrong link for the example. Can you please provide the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no straighforward way of doing this. Could you perhaps use the XMLEventReader to accomplish the same functionality?

Answer (score 2):

There's a common way of implementing recursive parsers that avoids the need for `unread` or `peek`, by pre-reading the next token, storing it, and testing against that:

- when you read in a token, you store it in a (global) variable.
- then you just test against it with all the tokens you're looking for (e.g. `<li>` and `</ul>`)
- when you've found the right one, you call the method that handles that (or continue)
- (which reads in the next token, having "consumed" the matching one)

In effect, you have *already* peeked ahead.

The 1st ed of the Dragon compiler book has a good example of this, in their early overview chapter, in C (they use Java in the 2nd ed, but it's unnecessarily overblown, IMHO - the C style works fine in Java).

I'll try to extract an example from my own source code, but my code is separated into a library layer with methods for handling the easier to use. I'll try to combine them to make a clear example, but it probably won't run standalone. Think of it as pseudo-code, to illustrate the idea, and you'll need to fill in the gaps.

```
XMLStreamReader in; 
int token;
String localname;

public void parse() {
  next();
  if (token==START_ELEMENT && localname.equals("ul")) ul();
}

void ul() {
  next();          // assume we are called when a <ul> is seen, so we consume it
  while (true) {   // loops for list
    if (token==START_ELEMENT && localname.equals("li")) li();  // ifs for choice 
    else if (token==START_ELEMENT && localname.equals("sometag")) sometag();
    else break;
  }
  if (token==END_ELEMENT && localname.equals("ul")) next();
  else throw new RuntimeException("expected </ul>");
       // <li> or <sometag> would also be acceptable
}

void li() {
  next();
  ...
}

void next() {
  token = in.next();         // consume the token means to set up the next one
  localname = in.getLocalName();
}
```

I found it much easier to use if you create a layer-library to handle the repetitive stuff, e.g. I have:

- `boolean startTag(String name)` just returns true if it matches
- `void requireStartTag(String name)` consumes if match, else throws exception

But I think the example is clearer keeping it all literal.

And there's other issues like skipping non-element tokens (like comments, PIs etc); tracking which line you're on for more helpful exceptions etc.